# Expandable listview in android using json parsing

Tags: android, json, expandablelistview

I have a problem with expandable ListView. The problem is that the list shows the group fields only, not the children. I am using expandable listview in navigation drawer.

This is my activity class:

```
public class NewsTabActivity extends Activity {

    public static String Id, LOGO, WEB_SERV, SUB_CAT, Font;
    ImageView image;
    ImageLoader imgloader;
    String URL_MAIN_CAT, nDrawerSubCat, URL_SUB_CAT, URL_HOME_PAGE;
    String[] mainCatName, mainCatId, mainCatId1, subCatParentID;
    JSONArray jarray,jarray1;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ExpandableListView mDrawerList;
    private ListView homeListview;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;

    ArrayList<NewsList> newsList;
    public ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    public HashMap<NewsDrawerItem, ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem>> navDrawerChildItems;
    private NewsDrawerItem newsDrawerItems;
    private NewsDrawerListAdapter adapter;
    NewsListAdapter adapter1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hometab);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        homeListview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        homeListview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        imgloader = new ImageLoader(NewsTabActivity.this);
        imgloader.DisplayImage(LOGO, image);
        nDrawerSubCat = SUB_CAT;

        System.out.println("DRAWER_SUBCAT ? = "+nDrawerSubCat);
        URL_HOME_PAGE = WEB_SERV + "homenews.php";
        URL_MAIN_CAT = WEB_SERV + "maincategory.php";

        if(nDrawerSubCat.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            URL_SUB_CAT = WEB_SERV + "subcategory.php";
            System.out.println("DRAWER_SUBCAT = "+URL_SUB_CAT);
        }

        newsList = new ArrayList<NewsList>();
        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem>();
        navDrawerChildItems = new HashMap<NewsDrawerItem, ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem>>();

        if (WebserviceUtils.isConnectingToInternet(NewsTabActivity.this)) {
            new NewsHomePage().execute(URL_HOME_PAGE);
            new NewsPaperMainCat().execute(URL_MAIN_CAT);
        }
        // adding nav drawer items to array
        mDrawerList.setOnGroupClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, // nav menu toggle icon
        R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
        // accessibility
        R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
        // accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle("News Live");
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle("News Live");
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView();
        }

    }

    /**
    * Slide menu item click listener
    * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
    ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener,ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            displayView();
            homeListview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            NewsListActivity.valuesID(navDrawerItems.get(groupPosition).getId());
            NewsListActivity.valueWEBSERV(WEB_SERV);
            System.out.println("NEWS_LIST_ID = "+navDrawerItems.get(groupPosition).getId());
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /* *
    * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
    */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
    * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
    * */
    private void displayView() {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        fragment = new NewsListActivity();

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("NewsTabActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }


    private class NewsHomePage extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private ProgressDialog p_dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            p_dialog = ProgressDialog.show(NewsTabActivity.this, "",
            "Loading...Please wait...", true);
            p_dialog.setCancelable(true);
            p_dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JsonParsor json = new JsonParsor();
            JSONObject jobject = json.getJSONFromUrl(URL_HOME_PAGE);

            try {
                JSONArray jarray = jobject.getJSONArray("news");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = jobj.getString("Id");
                    String cid = jobj.getString("c_id");
                    String title = jobj.getString("title");
                    String image = jobj.getString("image");

                    NewsList news = new NewsList();
                    news.setId(jobj.getString("Id"));
                    news.setCid(jobj.getString("c_id"));
                    news.setTitle(jobj.getString("title"));
                    news.setImage(jobj.getString("image"));
                    newsList.add(news);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "sucess";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            p_dialog.dismiss();
            if (result.compareTo("sucess") == 0) {
                adapter1 = new NewsListAdapter(NewsTabActivity.this,
                R.layout.newslist_single_item, newsList);
                homeListview.setAdapter(adapter1);
                adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(NewsTabActivity.this, "No data Found...",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }

    private class NewsPaperMainCat extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private ProgressDialog p_dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            p_dialog = ProgressDialog.show(NewsTabActivity.this, "",
            "Loading...Please wait...", true);
            p_dialog.setCancelable(true);
            p_dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JsonParsor json = new JsonParsor();
            JSONObject jobject,jobject1=null;

            int j,i;
            ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem> item = new ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem>();
            navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem>();
            navDrawerChildItems = new HashMap<NewsDrawerItem, ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem>>();

            jobject = json.getJSONFromUrl(URL_MAIN_CAT);
            if(nDrawerSubCat.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                jobject1 = json.getJSONFromUrl(URL_SUB_CAT);
            }

            try {
                jarray = jobject.getJSONArray("categories");
                if(nDrawerSubCat.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                    jarray1 = jobject1.getJSONArray("categories");
                }

                for (i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    mainCatName = new String[jarray.length()];
                    mainCatId = new String[jarray.length()];

                    mainCatId[i] = jobj.getString("Id");
                    mainCatName[i] = jobj.getString("name");

                    String id = jobj.getString("Id");
                    String name = jobj.getString("name");

                    System.out.println("MAIN_ID = " + id + " NAME= " + name);

                    // adding nav drawer items to array
                    navDrawerItems.add(new NewsDrawerItem(mainCatName[i], mainCatId[i]));
                }

                if(nDrawerSubCat.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                    for (j = 0; j < jarray1.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject jobj = jarray1.getJSONObject(j);

                        //                  newsDrawerItems = new NewsDrawerItem();

                        mainCatName = new String[jarray.length()];
                        mainCatId1 = new String[jarray.length()];
                        subCatParentID = new String[jarray.length()];

                        mainCatId1[j] = jobj.getString("Id");
                        mainCatName[j] = jobj.getString("name");
                        subCatParentID[j] = jobj.getString("parent_id");

                        String id = jobj.getString("Id");
                        String name = jobj.getString("name");
                        String pID = jobj.getString("parent_id");

                        System.out.println("MAIN_SUB_ID = "+id+" NAME= "+name+" PARENT_ID = "+pID);

                        item = new ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem>();
                        item.add(new NewsDrawerItem(mainCatName[j], mainCatId1[j]));
                    }

                    item = new ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem>();
                    item.add(new NewsDrawerItem(mainCatName[j], mainCatId1[j]));
                    navDrawerChildItems.put(navDrawerItems.get(j), item);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            return "sucess";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            p_dialog.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (result.compareTo("sucess") == 0) {
                adapter = new NewsDrawerListAdapter(NewsTabActivity.this,
                navDrawerItems, navDrawerChildItems);
                mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else
                Toast.makeText(NewsTabActivity.this, "No data Found...",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


    public static void valueID(String id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Id = id;
    }

    public static void valueLogo(String logo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LOGO = logo;
    }

    public static void valueWebService(String webServ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WEB_SERV = webServ;
    }

    public static void valueSubCat(String subCat) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SUB_CAT = subCat;
    }

    public static void valueFont(String font) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Font = font;
    }

}
```

This is my Adapter class:

```
public class NewsDrawerListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    Context context;
    public ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    public HashMap<NewsDrawerItem, ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem>> navDrawerChildItems;

    public NewsDrawerListAdapter(
    Context context,
    ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem> navDrawerItems,
    HashMap<NewsDrawerItem, ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem>> navDrawerChildItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
        this.navDrawerChildItems = navDrawerChildItems;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.navDrawerChildItems.get(
        this.navDrawerItems.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childPosititon;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosititon,
    boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_listchild_item,
            null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
        .findViewById(R.id.title_child);

        txtListChild.setText("sdv");
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("getChildrenCount_GROUP_POS = "
        + navDrawerItems.get(groupPosition).getChildItem().size());
        return navDrawerItems.get(groupPosition).getChildItem().size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.navDrawerItems.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("GROUP_COUNT = " + navDrawerItems.size());
        return this.navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
    View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater
            .inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
        .findViewById(R.id.title);
        lblListHeader.setText(Html.fromHtml(navDrawerItems.get(groupPosition).getTitle()));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

This is the model class:

```
public class NewsDrawerItem {

    private String title, Id, PId;
    private int icon;

    private ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem> childItemList = new ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem>();

    public NewsDrawerItem() {
    }

    public NewsDrawerItem(String title, String Id) {
        this.title = title;
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public NewsDrawerItem(String title, String Id, String PId) {
        this.title = title;
        this.Id = Id;
        this.PId = PId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.Id;
    }

    public String getPId() {
        return this.PId;
    }


    public int getIcon() {
        return this.icon;
    }

    public ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem> getChildItem() {
        System.out.println("CHILD_ITEM = "+childItemList);
        return childItemList;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setId(String Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public void setPId(String PId) {
        this.PId = PId;
    }

    public void setIcon(int icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public void setChildItem(ArrayList<NewsDrawerItem> childItemList) {
        this.childItemList = childItemList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please supply urls. Or put the json text in doInBackground so it does not have to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS WORK FOR ME TRY IT

**This is HomeFragment java class**

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
        private static String url = "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt";
        private ProgressDialog mprocessingdialog;
        private TextView tv_welcomeuser, tv_recentupdate;
        private ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
        private ExpandableListView exp_leaseoffer;
        private List<String> listDataHeader;
        private View rootView;
        private HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wellcome_page, container, false);
            tv_welcomeuser = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_welcomeuser);
            tv_recentupdate = (TextView) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_recentupdate);

            exp_leaseoffer = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

            new DownloadJason().execute();

            return rootView;
        }

        private class DownloadJason extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
                mprocessingdialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                mprocessingdialog.setTitle("Please Wait..");
                mprocessingdialog.setMessage("Loading");
                mprocessingdialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                mprocessingdialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
                JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
                String jsonstr = jp.makeServiceCall(url, JSONParser.GET);
                Log.d("Json url view", jsonstr);

                if (jsonstr != null) {

                    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
                    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
                        JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");
                        for (int hk = 0; hk < jarray.length(); hk++) {
                            JSONObject d = jarray.getJSONObject(hk);
                            // Adding Header data

                            listDataHeader.add(d.getString("country"));
                            // Adding child data for lease offer
                            List<String> lease_offer = new ArrayList<String>();

                            lease_offer.add(d.getString("country") + "'s Rank is : "
                                    + d.getString("rank"));
                            lease_offer.add("And Population is "+d.getString("population"));
                            // Header into Child data
                            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(hk), lease_offer);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Please Check internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                mprocessingdialog.dismiss();

                expandableListAdapter = new info.tranetech.adurec.fragments.Expandable_adapter(
                        getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);
                Log.i("groups", listDataHeader.toString());
                Log.i("details", listDataChild.toString());
                exp_leaseoffer.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);

                exp_leaseoffer.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                            int groupPosition, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return false;
                    }

                });
                // Listview Group expanded listener
                exp_leaseoffer
                        .setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                                // Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                // listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                exp_leaseoffer
                        .setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                                + " Collapsed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        });
                exp_leaseoffer.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                        // Toast.makeText(
                        // getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        // listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                        // + " : "
                        // + listDataChild.get(
                        // listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                        // childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        // .show();

    //                  Intent ilk = new Intent(getActivity(),
    //                          Lease_Offer_one.class);
    //                  startActivity(ilk);

                        return false;
                    }
                });

            }
        }

        // public Boolean isWifiAvailable() {
        //
        // try {
        // ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
        // getActivity()
        // .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // NetworkInfo wifiInfo = connectivityManager
        // .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        //
        // if (wifiInfo.isConnected()) {
        // return true;
        // }
        // } catch (Exception e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        // }
        // return false;
        // }

        // public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        // ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
        // getActivity()
        // .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
        // .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        // return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
        // }

    }

    **This is Expandable_adapter java class**




    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Expandable_adapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private Context _context;
        private List<String> _listDataHeader;
        private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

        public Expandable_adapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild) {
            this._context = context;
            this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
            this._listDataChild = listDataChild;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .get(childPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child, null);
            }
            TextView expandedListTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_listchild);
            expandedListTextView.setText(childText);
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return this._listDataHeader.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
            }
            TextView listTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_listtitle);
            listTitle.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            listTitle.setText(headerTitle);
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }

**xml wellcome_page**


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_welcome" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_welcomeuser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="WELCOME USER"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/eeeee"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_welcomeuser"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_recentupdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="RECENT UPDATES"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/expl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/header"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eeeee"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/textLin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="4" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_adurec"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lvExp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="times_roman"
                android:text="   Powered by "
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,HardcodedText,SpUsage" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_adurec"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="ADUREC"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,HardcodedText" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lvExp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textLin"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/buttons_effacts"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="0.8dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        </ExpandableListView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

**list_child.xml **

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_listchild"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#7D1023"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>

**list_group.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_listtitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons_effacts"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```